# OpenXml and strange behavior

Tags: c#, excel, cell, openxml

I have the following code:

```
            for (int r = 0; r < rows.Count(); r++)
            {
                var cells = rows[r].Elements<Cell>().ToList();
                for (int c = 0; c < cells.Count(); c++)
                {
                    SharedStringTablePart shareStringPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
                    SharedStringItem[] items = shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ToArray();
                    int v = int.Parse(cells[c].CellValue.Text);
                    text = items[v].InnerText;
                }
```

and the following excel file:

[image]

but this code is crashed with

I debug it and look at `CellValue` (my `v` variable) for every cell of row #2.

cell[0] = `33` (and it get correct value `PQ-10387`)

cell[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaPpk.jpg) = `22`

cell[2] = `198`

but

cell[3] = `310` and this value is the same value of cell! What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found, that when cell stores a number, then `CellValue` has value of cell and `DataType` is null, otherwise `DataType` has value and `CellValue` stores index. So, this code works fine:

```
            for (int r = 0; r < rows.Count(); r++)
            {
                var cells = rows[r].Elements<Cell>().ToList();
                for (int c = 0; c < cells.Count(); c++)
                {
                    SharedStringTablePart shareStringPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
                    SharedStringItem[] items = shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ToArray();
                    if (cells[c].DataType != null)
                    {
                        if (cells[c].CellValue != null)
                        {
                            int v = int.Parse(cells[c].CellValue.Text);
                            text = items[v].InnerText;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        text = cells[c].CellValue?.Text;
```